# Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

This line in my controller:

```
@feedback = Feedback.where("reviewer_id = ?, reviewee_id = ?, strength_id = ?", current_user.id, @report_for.id, @context ).first
```

produces this error when I attempt to display `@feedback.something`:

```
Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT  `feedbacks`.* FROM `feedbacks` WHERE (reviewer_id = 1, reviewee_id = 10, strength_id = 0) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your SQL is wrong, try this

```
@feedback = Feedback.where("reviewer_id = ? and reviewee_id = ? and strength_id = ?", current_user.id, @report_for.id, @context ).first
```